# Is there any software that can monitor and undo all registry changes automatically?

Tags: windows, display, windows-registry, undo

Is there any software that can monitor and undo all registry changes automatically?

It would be better if there is an option to monitor all changes or changes made by a specific process.

Comment: Try to restore the system. Restore is the best option available in Windows to make changes back.

Comment: @avirk system restore does more than that can remove files from the desktop, and it's purely backup, so it only works on a time basis. There is ERUNT which does just the registry, but also since it's a backup program, it won't be as good as an uninstaller for monitoring and undoing just a specific installation.

Comment: @barlop I have never seen its remove files from the desktop. Just the program that you have installed on the system earlier. Restore point will work only on the programs not with the files.

Comment: @avirk i've had lots of experience with system restore. my experience has been in XP.  I'm right. Programs consist of files by the way. I haven't tested this in a while but try putting an EXE file on the desktop then doing a system restore and see if it is still there, i'd strongly suspect it won't be. See here too http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/UserTips/Miscellaneous/SystemRestoreandtheDesktop.html     You have to think about how things work.. It doesn't just push the Program files directory back(to an extent perhaps), it pushes the desktop back(to an extent)

Comment: @barlop when I used system restore in 7 recently, it stated explicitly that your files will not be modified. Restoring from a backup would cause that but it appears that in windows 7, system restore is more of a timeline of system changes, ignoring user files.

Answer (score 2):

There was a dedicated tool from Microsoft named [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652) for monitoring. Now, its replaced by [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Process Monitor displays Registry activities too.

When it comes to monitoring and undoing both, [SpyMe Tools](http://www.lcibrossolutions.com/spymetools) will be great. To detect Registry changes it creates Dumps of the actual states of Registry. This means that at any time you can open the Dump file and view the contents of the Registry just as they were when you've scanned the Registry. The program can compare two different dump files so you'll see exactly what changed in the Registry between the two scans.

If you are interested in 100% clean un-installation of softwares, use [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). It monitors every activity of an installer at the time of installation. It undoes these changes at the time of uninstallation. It works great. But, as a limitation of any uninstaller, you can undo only those registry changes which are tied with an installation and you'll need to uninstall a software to undo any registry changes did by it. So, I'm recommending [SpyMe Tools](http://www.lcibrossolutions.com/spymetools) again.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Revo Uninstaller *Pro* is not free.

Comment: I know.. The question doesn't specify that the required software must be free..

Comment: I know.. Still worth mentioning it though..

Comment: k.. but, still there're ways to get it free (when its important)... I don't want to specify those ways..

Comment: yes but if they knew they'd know and if they don't they wouldn't.. but mentioning that it's not freeware would save them some hassle 'cos even if they did take it illegally, they'd have to scan it(installing a virus checker if they haven't), and there may be a high probability of it containing a virus.. it's still less hassle if it's freeware, you could word it as not freeware, to be clearer! also, in a sense, anything's free, by that reasoning, you just need a balaclava and some skill!

Comment: Ok... my dear..

Answer (score 0):

I have used Total Uninstall, that program still exists, for Windows XP and 7 and so on.. and looks like it'd do about the same as it did then.

http://www.martau.com/

Any uninstaller program might do it, but I remember Total Uninstall as being a great program years ago like in the windows 98 days.
There was also a program called In Control from PC Magazine..but didn't offer undo/redo. There's Sysinternals Process Monitor which takes over sysinternals regmon, which also doesn't offer undo/redo.  But Total Uninstall actually lets you undo or redo, and did it without any baggage in the GUI too. I'd give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already tried TU but didn't like the way it works.TU gets registry and file system changes by comparing two system snapshots. Process Monitor plus undo feature should be exactly what I need:D